# Update df with new data from another df in python

Tags: python, pandas

I just want to update a old dataframe with data from a new dataframe. I have tried everything.. and I can't find it. This should be easy... right?

Old df:

| Id | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa* |
| 2 | BBB |

New df:

| Id | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA |
| 3 | CCC |

Updated df:

| Id | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA |
| 2 | BBB |
| 3 | CCC |

I have tested concat, join, update and merge...  :(

Answer (score 2):

You can concatenate the dataframes, and drop the duplicates, keeping the ones in df2, then sort by the id column:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates('Id', keep='last').sort_values('Id')
```

Output:

```
   Id Value
0   1   AAA
1   2   BBB
1   3   CCC
```

Data:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
Id  Value
1   aaa*
2   BBB
"""), sep="\s+")

df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
Id  Value
1   AAA
3   CCC
"""), sep="\s+")
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used one more right join. This should give you correct answer.

```
import pandas as pd

old_df = pd.DataFrame({'Id': [1, 2], 'Value': ['aaa*', 'BBB']})
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'Id': [1, 3], 'Value': ['AAA', 'CCC']})

updated_df_left = old_df.merge(new_df, on='Id', how='left', suffixes=('_old', ''))
updated_df_right = old_df.merge(new_df, on='Id', how='right', suffixes=('_old', ''))

updated_df_left['Value'] = updated_df_left['Value'].fillna(updated_df_left['Value_old'])
updated_df1 = updated_df_left.drop(columns=['Value_old'])

updated_df2 = updated_df_right.drop(columns=['Value_old'])

finalRes = pd.concat([updated_df1,updated_df2]).drop_duplicates()

print(finalRes)
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I know what I did wrong, I didn't have unique id's and when creating this and with your answers it is working!

Answer (score 1):

When updating, [combin_first](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) is often useful.

```
df2.set_index('Id').combine_first(df1.set_index('Id')).reset_index()
```

output:

```
    Id  Value
0   1   AAA
1   2   BBB
2   3   CCC
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option, where I'm using `index` to update the data. In this method, I'm not assumption about which row to keep (`first` or `last` in case of duplication). Also not doing merge (index merge is much faster), which is computationally expensive. Just `setting IDs as index`, `updating value by index column` and `resetting index to ids following by combining 2 datasets`,

```
# Create a list of dates
df_old = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2],
                   'value': ['aaa*', 'BBB']})

df_new = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,3],
                   'value': ['AAA', 'CCC']})

# Set 'id' as the index for both dataframes for the update operation
df_old.set_index('id', inplace=True)
df_new.set_index('id', inplace=True)

# Update values from df_new into df_old
df_old.update(df_new)

# Reset the index
df_old.reset_index(inplace=True)

df_update = pd.concat([df_old, df_new.reset_index()], axis = 0).drop_duplicates()
print(df_update)

id value
0   1   AAA
1   2   BBB
1   3   CCC
```